# haskell converting an Int list to a string

Tags: haskell

I am working with bits that are represented by 0 and 1
I have this bit list [[1...16],[17...32],[33...48]] and I want to correspond for each 8 bits a char and join all at the end with function chr, or other that does the same thing, and assuming that I have a function that converts [Bit]->Int. For example

```
  [[1...16],[17...32],[33...48]]
  [1...8] = char one
  [9...16] = char two
  [17...24] = char three
  [25...32] = char four

  Then I want to make a String = char one ++ char two ++ char three ++ char four.
```

Thanks.

Comment: My problem is separate that list and apply a function on it.

Comment: Still don't see the problem... What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a function `fromBits :: [Bit] -> Int`, first split your input list into chunks of 8, for example using [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3achunksOf) from the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package, then, for each chunk, apply `fromBits` and use [`chr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v%3achr) to convert the resulting `Int` to `Char`.

```
map (chr . fromBits) $ chunksOf 8 input
```

Comment: The way the question's asked it looks like the chunks are done already, in which case it's just `map (chr.fromBits)`.